# How to mutate/write the property of an asset using Tandem API?

Tags: javascript, tandem, autodesk-tandem

I am trying change the value of a property of an asset using tabdem api. I am using mutate method provided in the tandem api but I'm unable to find how to change property value. It is asking key and value as argument for query param but I don't what yo give and from to fetch that values.

Please guide me as how to change the properties values using this method.

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G4Wt6.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYOqw.jpg)

I tried to find the values in the facility but I am not sure from I should get the property value in the facility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `mutate` endpoint you need to pass three inputs via payload.:

1. **keys** if array of element keys to modify
2. **muts** is array of array which describe change. Each element of array is array of 4 items:

- action (`i` means upsert = both create and update)
- property family
- property column
- property value

The property family and column can be obtained from [schema](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/tandem/v1/reference/quick_reference/tandem-data-schema-GET/). Use only properties which are part of applied classification.

3. **desc** is description of change. It is optional but can help you to find change in the history so it's recommended to put some useful info here.

Here is sample payload:

```
{
    "keys": [
        "IOURj_4LSP2Aon3zJE5quQAgVYM"
    ],
    "muts": [
        [ "i", "z", "1hw", "P010" ]
    ],
    "desc": "Update properties"
}
```

Note that size of keys and muts arrays should be same. You can update multiple elements in one call. In case when you want to modify multiple properties of same element then use same key multiple times.

You may want to check [this example](https://github.com/autodesk-tandem/tutorial-rest/blob/main/assets/write-asset-properties.js).

Comment: Understood Jan. But i am unaware what to use in this places. Can please guide me as from where I can get the key, property family, property column and property value for a asset to use it in this method?

Comment: I added note about schema which can be used to obtain values for family and classification. For value you specify new value for property.

Comment: Understood Jan. How do get the keys for the asset?

Comment: Depends on your workflow. For example you can use [scan endpoint](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/tandem/v1/reference/quick_reference/tandem-data-scan-POST/) to locate elements from your facility. In this case the key is available via **k** property.

Comment: But in the scan endpoint also key is given as input in the request then only we can get a response with k as property. Can you please clarify on this?

Comment: Right, in case of `scan` endpoint you can specify input keys in case you want to query specific elements only. Note this is optional - if not provided then all elements from given model are returned. Also consider that other options (`families`, `qualifiedColumns`) can be used to refine which data are returned. For example you want to get all elements with custom properties - then use `families` set to `[ "z" ]`.